# JComboBox popup cell height wrong after call to setSelectedItem()

Tags: java, popup, jcombobox

I want a drop-down compobox where the selected element is one-line when its not selected, but when I choose from the drop-down each cell is taller and shows some extra information

[image: Drop down cells are multiple lines]

This is achieved by the following code:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JList;

public class ComboJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private boolean popup;

    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;

    public ComboJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());

        DefaultComboBoxModel model = new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3",
                                                                                                                                                                         "Long Long Item 4" });
        jComboBox1.setModel(model);
        jComboBox1.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                System.out.println("rend = " + value);
                // if popup is showing we need to make elements tall
                if (popup) this.setText("<html>" + value.toString().replaceAll(" ", "<br/>\n"));
                return this;
            }
        ;
        });
                jComboBox1.addPopupMenuListener(new javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener() {
            public void popupMenuCanceled(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {
                popup = false;
                System.out.println("popup = " + popup);
            }

            public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {
                popup = false;
                System.out.println("popup = " + popup);
            }

            public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {
                popup = true;
                jComboBox1.invalidate();
                System.out.println("popup = " + popup);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jComboBox1);

        pack();

        model.setSelectedItem("Item 3");  // THIS GIVES THE PROBLEM
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ComboJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is what if I programatically select an item, like

```
        model.setSelectedItem("Item 3");
```

then the JCombobox gets the cell height wrong and displays

[image]

This is **only happening** on when selecting items programatically. If I select an item by manually clicking with the mouse and then opens the popup againd then it goes away.

Ive seen this on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 using Java 7 and Java 8.

I'd like to get it fixed, and to know whether Windows and Mac has the same problem.

Strange thing is, that if I add items to the model in a ways such that setSelectedItem is never called, like:

```
model.removeAllElements();
model.addElement("Item 3");
model.insertElementAt("Item 2",0);
model.insertElementAt("Item 1",0);
model.addElement("Long Item 4");
```

then the problem doesen't appear

Another workaround seems to be to select the item and then re-set the model:

```
model.setSelectedItem("Item 3");
jComboBox1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel());
jComboBox1.setModel(model);
```

The above is test code, the real application is for Apertium machine translation, and the combobox looks like this:

[image: Apertium-viewer combobox]

Comment: Have you considered using a `toolTip` instead

Comment: Yes - and no, its not an option.